# JavaScript wont work outside of content area wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Basically i am using wordpress and i want my share links to follow the post down as the user scrolls down. I can get it to work exactly how i want except i have attached the JavaScript directly to content.php and this means the JavaScript is loaded multiple times on the page when the page displays multiple posts. This is causing the sticky function to only work for the top few posts. I've tried moving my javascript to the header but with no luck. Please can somebody help me!! Below is my content.php file which only works on the top few posts.

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.js"></script><script src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.container').stickem();
        });
    </script><div class="title-wrapper"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments" title="<?php comments_number( 'No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?>"><div class="commentnumber"><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></div></a></div><div class="container"><div class="stickem-container"><div class="thelinks stickem"><div class="sharelinks"><div class="sharepinterest"><?php echo get_simple_local_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ); ?></div><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&p[images][0]=http://www.otlcampaign.org/sites/default/files/journey-for-justice-mlk-memorial.jpg&p[title]=<?php the_title(); ?>&p[summary]=Click+to+enlarge"><div class="sharefacebook"></div></a><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>+<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="sharetwitter"></div></a><div class="sharegoogle"></div></div></div>

    <div class="post-wrapper"><div class="entry-content"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a>
    </div></div></div>
    </div><a>
```

Comment: You should add the code to your footer.php file instead

Comment: What / if any errors do you get when you place it in the header?

Answer (score 1):

Try sticking it in your footer instead.

If that doesn't work, look for the container in console, and you can switch from

```
$(document).ready
```

to

```
$(".container").change
// or whatever the css selector for the container is
```

that way the stickem() will fire the moment the container changes, aka new posts load in.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to move the code into your footer.php file, and make the following changes:

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.container').stickem();
});
```

By default WordPress has jQuery no conflict enabled, so instead of using `$` you have to use `jQuery`. This also means you **don't** need to include:

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried this in footer to no avail. Have i did i right?. **<script src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.container').stickem();
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>**

Comment: That looks right. Apparently jQuery Stick Em only adds the classes so you have to write your own css, have you remembered to do this?

Comment: Will I need to change the css from what i had when the script was in content.php? if not then the css is there.

Comment: I recommend you move it to the header.php file, but it should still work. Can you clarify what doesn't work? Is 'This is causing the sticky function to only work for the top few posts.' still the problem? Does it work on some posts? What doesn't work about the other posts?

Comment: The 'causing the sticky function to only work for the top few posts' which means the 1, 2 or 3 posts (Changes every time i refresh the page) only have the sticky function then the rest of the posts are not sticky. This happens when the JavaScript is in content.php. Anywhere else i try it (Header or footer) the sticky function just doesn't work at all for any of the posts.

Comment: Are you using something like infinite scroll? Is there something different with the first 3 posts, maybe a different post type or something?

Comment: Im not using anything like infinite scroll. All the posts are the same type. It just seems as if the sticky JavaScript doesn't load on some of the posts. I think if you scroll down before the page has fully loaded it breaks.

Comment: Do you mind posting a link (you can edit/delete it after)? The only thing that would exclude the posts would be if they didn't have the `container` class.

Comment: its locally hosted on my computer ill have to upload it to my server which could take a while. do you mind if i get back to you tomorrow with a link?